Cython interacting with python when using custom sigmoid function
I made a sigmoid function in cython using exp from libc.math, so the function itself doesn't interact with python. However, when I use it in another function, it interacts with cython and I have no idea why.

Does anyone know why this happens and how can I fix this?
Here's the code
from libc.math cimport exp

@cython.exceptval(check=False)
@cython.cdivision(True) # turn off checking for division by zero
cdef inline float sigmoid(float x, float lamda):
    return 1 / (1 + exp(-lamda * x))

@cython.exceptval(check=False)
@cython.cdivision(True)         # turn off checking for division by zero
cdef inline float sigmoid_grad(float x, float lamda):
    return -lamda * sigmoid(x, lamda) * (1 - sigmoid(x, lamda))


I addeed @cython.exceptval(check=False) but still not resolved

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I think in this case an image of the highlighted code is fine (because it's a useful output that's difficult to capture in plain text). But the original code should still be included as text to help reproduce it.

The Python interactions only occur in the case of an exception being thrown from your function.
You can use Cython noexcept (@cython.exceptval(check=False)) to mark your functions as never throwing any exceptions. That way, Cython won't need this check.
More at https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#error-return-values

Only thing to add is that in Cython versions <3 cdef functions silently swallowed exceptions by default so in those versions noexcept wouldn't have been needed.

I added @cython.exceptval(check=False) but it doesn't seem to solve the case.

You might need to use the alternative syntax with noexcept after the function name and argument list instead.

Yep that solved it. Thanks a lot!
